# How to say protect & conquer in Latin

Tags: motto, english-to-latin-translation

I am getting a tattoo of my two boys names - Vincent and Alexander. To make it interesting I am going with the meaning of the names in Latin rather than the names themselves. So I understand Vincent derives its meaning from "to conquer", and Alexander from "protector/defender of men". As the space I am tattooing is limited, I want to write "CONQUER DEFEND" in capitals. At present, *VINCERE* seems pretty straight forward, but I am having issues with the Alexander side. I think I could use *SANCTUM, FORTIS, SPIRITUS, SERVO*.

Also, does this all change if you want it to read as one instead of two separate words? E.g. translate "to protect & conquer". Remember limited space.

Answer (score 2):

Alright so it's really about mixing and matching and finding what looks and sounds good to you. I will provide translations for both words to choose from, and then show you how to combine them.

**Conquer**

- *vincere* (this reflects Vincent nicely (as it is the origin of said name), so the next option is just for kicks)
- *domare* (as in dominate)

**Defend**

Unfortunately, Alexander is Greek in origin, so there is no Latin verb from which it derives, so these are all just translations of "to protect."

- *servare*
- *tegere*
- *tutare*
- *munire*
- *arcere*

Some options have been omitted due to length.

**Putting it Together**

Now, as in English, one would normally join two clauses like this with a conjunction such as "and." Latin can do the same thing, and provides two options that are pretty common (even in English).

1. *et* as in *VINCERE ET ARCERE* (This one is most familiar to non-Latin English speakers, as it appears in common phrases such as "*et tu, Brute*")
2. *-que* as in VINCERE ARCEREQVE (The *-que* is a suffix of the second word)

You could omit a conjunction as well, to reflect the English example you gave ("CONQUER DEFEND" -> *VINCERE ARCERE*).

You will also notice that I capitalized all of the letters in these examples and replaced any u's with V's. This is how the Romans would write inscriptions on monuments and such (see [here](http://dl.ket.org/latin2/grammar/images/inscription.jpg)), so it makes sense to me to do it like that on a tattoo, especially if you use a similar font.

You may have noticed that I used *arcere* in all of my examples. I like this one the best especially when paired with the *-que* conjunction because of the consonance with the c's and q (even if it becomes somewhat of a tongue twister!). However, it is up to you to choose the words that you prefer best, as well as the conjunction. I hope this assists you, and good luck!

---

If anyone knows of any verbs that derive from the Greek words that were the original source of Alexander, I'd be very interested to hear about them.

Comment: For the verb root of alex-, see the LSJ entries for ἀλέξω and then ἄλαλκε.

Comment: Also, according to the StarLing PIE database, [the root *alek- is found only in Greek, Indo-Iranian and Germanic](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?single=1&basename=%2fdata%2fie%2fpiet&text_number=1293&root=config). Unfortunately for little Alexander, there is no direct descendant in Latin.